# Adding parameters to query with a path source

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have query code from excel:

```
= if Date.Month(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{5}[start])=Date.Month(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CurrentDate"]}[Content]{0}[CurrentDate]) then Source else Table.Combine({Source, Csv.Document(File.Contents(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Request"]}[Content]{3}[Path]),null,{0, 55, 62, 134, 145, 386, 398, 410},null,1200)})
```

Instead of `Excel.CurrentWorkbook()` (since im trying to use this query in powerbi and in powerbi there is no `"CurrentWorkbook"`) I have to use path `"X:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.txt"`

Changeing it like this doesn't work

```
= if Date.Month("X:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.txt"[Content]{5}[start])=Date.Month("X:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.txt"[Content]{0}[CurrentDate]) then Source else Table.Combine({Source, Csv.Document(File.Contents("X:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.txt"[Content]{3}[Path]),null,{0, 55, 62, 134, 145, 386, 398, 410},null,1200)})
```

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type Text.
Details:
    Value=X:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.txt
    Key=Content
```

These [Content] {5} and [Content] {0} I think are required since these apply to columns start date and current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a continuation of your earlier question about using a comma separated text file. I believe what you might be looking for is:

```
Csv.Document(File.Contents("X:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.txt"),null,",",null,1200)[Column#OfYourStartColumn]{6}
```

Replace Column#OfYourStartColumn with Column and the number of the column that is your start column: like Column1 if your start column is your first column, or Column3 if it is your third.

Use 6 as the index reference, instead of 5, because your first row will be the column names from your actual txt file.